# How can I rollback many transactions in Rails together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

Let's say we have an app that allows users to create a schedule for intramural sports.

Alice wants to schedule Team A vs Team B on Jan 1 at 6:00pm.

So let's say we have two models.

a **Game** model that holds **id, date**

a **Competitor** model that **holds id, game_id, team_id, home**

Let's Team A is team_id 100 and Team B is team_id 101.

Our game model will create a new entry,

```
game.id = 1, date = Jan 1 6:00pm.
```

Our competitor model will create 2 new entries.

```
id = assigned, game_id: 1, team_id: 100, home: true
id = assigned, game_id: 1, team_id: 101, home: false
```

Let's say I'm saving this together. How can I roll back the game entry, and competitor entry if say there is an error on the save of the second competitor entry.

Should I have something like this?...

```
Game.transaction do
  Competitor.transaction do
    ...
    team = ...
    opponent_team = ...
    home = home?(team)
    ...
    game = Game.new(date: game_start_date)
    if game.save
      competitor_team = Competitor.new(game_id: game.id, team_id: team.id, home: home)
      if competitor_team.save
        competitor_opponent = Competitor.new(game_id: game.id, team_id: opponent_team.id, home: !home)
        if competitor_opponent.save
          #Do nothing
        else
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, competitor_opponent.errors.full_messages
        end
      else
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, competitor_team.errors.full_messages
      end
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, game.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
end
```

Will those rollbacks roll back every transactions committed? If competitor_opponent.save fails, will it roll back the game.save and the competitor_team.save?

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught exceptions will automatically roll back any transactions that are affected.

It's not necessary to raise any particular kind of exception, so you can raise something that describes your error more accurately. Throwing exceptions from another class seems dishonest here.

Note that depending on your database engine certain kinds of operations may not be captured in a transaction. For example, MySQL does not transactionalize changes to the schema. Certain engines may not even support transactions at all, like MySQL + MyISAM.

Comment: 1) So basically I can remove all of the else ActiveRecord::Rollback code? 2) Will I still get output to the console? 3) I'm good so long as I leave the Game.transaction and Competitor.transaction code then, correct? What if those were removed, and I was just doing the .save's?

Comment: If you want output to the console, just `raise "custom error message"` or whatever seems necessary. It may not be necessary to nest transactions like that if they're both on the same database, either, so test how it works in both a success and failure state. You can also clean this up a lot by using `save!` which automatically throws an exception on failure.

Comment: will `save!` stop everything dead in its tracks? I'm looping through creating hundreds of events. If one event fails, I don't want the code to terminate and not create the remaining events.